# Functional class level arguments in Java 8

Tags: java, design-patterns, java-8, functional-programming

I would like to make more of an effort to use Java 8's functional features and shift my thinking towards that paradigm; however, I'm not quite sure how to reconcile this scenario.

For example I recently wrote something similar to this:

```
public class ExampleClass {

    private ExampleData exampleData;
    private Function<ExampleData, Boolean> workFunction;

    public ExampleData getExampeData() {
        return exampleData;
    }

    public void setExampleData(ExampleData exampleData) {
        this.exampleData = exampleData;
    }

    public Function<ExampleData, Boolean> getWorkFunction() {
        return workFunction;
    }

    public void setWorkFunction(Function<ExampleData, Boolean> workFunction) {
        this.workFunction = workFunction;
    }
}
```

then I proceed to use it like so...

```
public class Worker implements Callable {

    private final ExampleClass exampleClass;

    // ExampleClass serves as a container for the function and it's
    // input data in order to minimize the number of arguments
    // passed to this constructor. Otherwise would be
    // public Worker(ExampleData exampleData, Function<T, R> workFunction, ...) {
    // Note: using "..." here to represent more args.
    public Worker(ExampleClass exampleClass, ...) {
        this.exampleClass = exampleClass;
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void call() {
        final Boolean isComplete = exampleClass.getWorkFunction().apply(exampleClass.getExampleData());
        if (isComplete) {
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Would something like the above be preferred over what I would consider the more traditional approach?

```
public class ExampleClass {

    private ExampleData exampleData;

    public ExampleClass(ExampleData exampleData) {
        this.exampleData = exampleData;
    }

    public Boolean work() {
          return isComplete(exampleData);
    }
}
```

and the implementing class...

```
public class Worker implements Callable {

    private ExampleClass exampleClass;

    public Worker(ExampleClass exampleClass, ...) {
        this.exampleClass = exampleClass;
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void call() {
        final Boolean isComplete = exampleClass.work();
        if (isComplete) {
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

If I'm completely off base, what would be a proper functional solution using Java 8?

**Update:** Lets say my example doesn't return a Boolean. In the context of functional programming with Java 8, is it better to explicitly pass a function as a class level argument or is it better to just use the traditional object oriented way of just passing another class that performs that function?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please take the [tour] and visit our [help] to learn what kinds of questions are appropriate for this site.  Opinion-based questions such as this are off-topic, as they tend to result in angry debates here.  If you can [edit] your question to fit the requirements of this site, please do so.

Comment: It’s hardly an opinion based question. By that definition all design pattern questions would be a matter of opinion.

Comment: There are different opinions about what is "opinion based" ;-) The main issue with your code is IMHO that it is too vague and sketchy. An `ExampleClass` may be helpful to get an idea across, but here, this is not the case: It is not clear what this class is supposed to be (i.e. how it could map to a "real world class"), and what the `Function` part is supposed to accomplish. The way it is, it looks highly dubious (as if you had thrown in the `Function` randomly, because ... functional!!!111), but maybe there's a deeper meaning/intention/goal behind this...?!

Comment: More specifically: The `ExampleClass` is basically a POJO, consisting of two elements: The data and the function. And the *only* way how this class is used is by obtaining the data and the function, and doing something with them. The class itself does not seem to serve any purpose, beyond being a "container". Maybe a more realistic example could make the question clearer.

Comment: The ExampleClass is a POJO. Its only purpose is to minimize the number of arguments passed to the Worker class. I guess my question doesn't have a lot to do with the ExampleClass, its more about explicitly passing functions as class level arguments vs passing classes that perform functions. I've updated my question to hopefully clarify that.

Comment: Looks to me like you're needlessly inverting the usual OOP pattern of encapsulating data and behavior just so you can make your code more "functional". Everything has its place, and the place of functional programming is when you need to specifically pass behavior. But it is pretty opinion-based, at least in my opinion...

Comment: To me it looks the same and so I’m trying to figure out of if there are any advantages of doing so and if not is there a more “functional” Java 8 way. It seems nice to be able to pass any function to the worker class, but of course you can have the same kind of flexibility with a regular interface or base class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of Functional programming is that The function must be treated as an object.

but you know, function(method) is not object in java. it is differ to javascript.

so, we should use interface called Predicate.

```
List<Apple> apples = new ArrayList<>();
```

you want to get weight apples. originally,

```
List<Apple> weightApples = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; 9< apples.size(); i++){
    if(apples.getWeight() > 10){
        weightApples.add(apples.get(i));
    }
}
```

this code.

in functional programming, function is be 'pure function'.

in pure function, You should avoid using external variables in functions.

and, we dont care function's logic in 'the line using function'

first, we need predicdate interface.

```
interface Predicate<T>{
    public boolean pass(T t);
}
```

by generic, we can extend object type.

we can make filter.

```
public static <T> List<T> filter(List<T> list, Predicate<T> predicate){
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for(T el : list){
        if(predicate.pass(el)){
            result.add(el);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

the pass() is not implemented not yet.

it can implemented by annonymous class.

finally, method is treated like object by use lamda!

```
filter(apples, (Apple apple) -> apple.getWeight()>10);
```

i'm not people in english, so it is poor english.

but i hope it is helpful for you! thanks.

Comment: This does help, but let’s say I modified my example so that the function I was looking to pass did not return a Boolean thus would not work as a predicate and that I was trying to pass a function to a Worker thread that extends from Callable or Runnable meaning the function has to be passed through the constructor to be used in its overridable run method. Is it okay to have a container class that holds a function?

Comment: Question about this. Does avoiding external variables mean avoiding class level variables passed in through a constructor? If so does that mean to every class should be static to actually use java in a purely functional way?

Comment: it is not. it is the issue about function(method). then, function should be avoid  applied by external variable. static variable must deliberately be used.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a function that accepts one argument and returns a boolean should implement [Java 8 `Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html).

However, in my opinion, predicates were not meant to replace any and all `if` statements. They are meant to be used as filters in Java 8's collection streams.  The example you provided does not seem to fit this situation.